# odoo import .xlsx sale_order, purchase_order

Tags: python, odoo, xlsx, odoo-10

what I'm trying to do here is importing an .xlsx to `sale_order`
the code below explains how i did it using csv.DictReader(). in order to get that to work on .xlsx file I found [XLS to Dict Reader using xlrd](https://gist.github.com/mdellavo/639082), and I have no idea how to implement that.

ps: I'm new with python and odoo 10

```
file_data = fields.Binary('Archive', required=True,)

def import_button(self):
    file_path = tempfile.gettempdir()+'/file.csv'
    data = self.file_data
    f = open(file_path,'wb')
    f.write(data.decode('base64'))
    f.close() 
    archive = csv.DictReader(open(file_path),delimiter=';')

    archive_lines = []
    for line in archive:
        archive_lines.append(line)
```

> Edit: i did use that function `XLSDictReader` :

```
> archive = XLSDictReader(open(file_path))
```

> and I got this error `'import.purchase.order' object has no attribute 'fileno'`

Comment: Are you attempting to open a file in python and save it as an excel file? Could you use pandas instead?

Comment: yes I am, and I have no idea how to use pandas !. something is missing here and I don't know what it is

Comment: if you have pandas installed (if not $pip install pandas in your terminal) try

`df = pd.read_csv(r'your\file\path\to\csv.csv')`  then.. 
`df.to_excel('your_file_name.xlsx)` if I understand this correctly it should be quite simple. a more seasoned python expert will need to make sense of your code as it makes none to me.

Comment: thanks @Datanovice , i think i'm about to understand what's wrong with my code. after reading Pands Doc, all I need is to write the datas in a new .xlsx file, then run XLSDictReader () ti fill my new object in th data base

Comment: once you figure it out post your answer here buddy! make sure your answers are clear and easy to understand for others to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always with xlrd, thank you Mr. @Datanovice for your help

```
def import_button(self):
    file_path = tempfile.gettempdir()+'/file.xls'
    data = self.file_data
    f = open(file_path,'wb')
    f.write(data.decode('base64'))
    f.close() 

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path, on_demand = True)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
        first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
    # transform the workbook to a list of dictionaries
    archive_lines = []
    for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
        elm = {}
        for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
            elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)

        archive_lines.append(elm)
```